# Putting "spread" on a bread in Latin

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin, cibus

There are various kinds of spreads one can put on a bread, made from butter, vegetable oils, or other ingredients.
What would be a good general word for these products for use in contemporary Latin?

If at all possible, I would like a word that is not a variation on *butyrum* or any other word referring to butter.
Butter is a kind of spread, and I am looking for a word that would include butter but would include, say, margarine and hummus.
I want to translate the noun "spread" to Latin, but it doesn't have to be literally about spreading.

I have posted one suggestion below, but I doubt it's the only option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Savoury spreads**:
An earlier question on *[pesto](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5780/how-to-translate-pesto)* gave two invented answers. Another is
Gentleman's Relish, an anchovy flavoured spread that used the mock Latin description 'Patum Peperium,' ([also the title of its website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentleman%27s_Relish)) hence *patum,* and *patulum.* And yet another invented name could have been added from *tapenade,* the olive paste from SE France whose root is *tapet, tapetia,* a carpet, a covering (fr, Greek).

> There is also *salsa, salsorum,* salted foods (Plautus): genuine Latin.

Then there are two **spreads: pastes, patées** eaten with bread which may be sweet **or** savoury. ***Pulmentum*** seems to be the most appropriate.

> *pulmentārĭum, ĭi,* n. [L&S](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/perseus/getobject.pl?c.14:6254.LewisShort18) 
>   also *pulmentum, i,* n. contr. from *pulpamentum,* from *pulpa.* 
>    Any thing eaten with bread, a relish (fruit, salt, mustard, etc.)
>
> *crĕmor, ōris,* m. (kindr. with *cremo,* (1)) the thick juice obtained from animal or vegetable substances, broth, purée

The **most successful spread** with an invented Latin name is **Margarine,** ([culinarylore.com](https://culinarylore.com/food-science:margarine-myths-feed-t%20%20urkeys-and-more/))

> Margarine was invented in France by Hippolyte Mège-Mouriès in 1869, during  the Franco-Prussian wars. He invented it in response to a competitive  challenge from the French government under Napoleon III. His product was pale yellow and had a pleasant buttery smell; it was cheaper than butter and lasted longer (It was a manufactured from beef fat)

The name, based on the Latin word for 'pearl,' comes from the small glistening droplets which appeared during the first successful experiments.

[Mège-Mouriès might easily have chosen to derive the name from *lino, linere,* to smear or daub; and *oleum,* olive oil, grease.  But fortunately, five years earlier that name had been taken, though not registered,...

> Linoleum was invented by an Englishman Frederick Walton in 1855; from 1864 he called it Linoleum, which he derived from the Latin words "linum" (flax) and "oleum" (oil).]

Comment: +1 for some valid classical options.

Answer (score 4):

A good verb for spreading seems to be *pandere*.
From "spread" one can derive "spreadable", and such derivations are widely attested in classical Latin:

- *facilis < facere*
- *fragilis < frangere*
- *utilis < uti*

An adjective can always be substantivized to mean the thing the verb is applied to.
For this specific class of adjectives, two prominent examples come to mind:

- *sedile < sedere*
- *missile < mittere*

Applying the same derivations to *pandere* leads to ***pandile*** (lit. "spreadable thing").
While I'm not aware of any attestations of this word, it is derived in a natural and attested way.
It is conveniently short and should be understandable in context.

As Tom Cotton suggested in a comment, one can also use *-men* or *-mentum*.
It seems that with third conjugation verbs this is often tied to the verb with *-i-*, so we get the alternative options ***pandimen*** and ***pandimentum***.

Comment: Might we also consider _pandamen_ or _pandamentum_?

Comment: @TomCotton Good idea! According to a quick look-up, it seems that the *-a-* is only used for first conjugation verbs, whereas the third conjugation gets *-imen(tum)*. I edited that in. (It would be interesting know whether there are hard rules for the choice of vowel before *-men(tum)*; I only looked up some examples.)

Comment: I didn't spot that. We learn something new every day!

Comment: While _pandimen_ / _pandimentum_ is reasonable - I'm thinking of the Italian _condimento_ (seasoning, condiment) - I would lean towards _pandile_, as in Italian we say _spalmabile_ for spreadable products, and indeed sometimes (when it's cheese) we may leave it unspecified. Besides, _pandere_ is very similar to the Italian _spandere_, a synonym of _spalmare_.