# How to search for nouns ending in -ile?

Tags: resource-request, dictionary

When I was researching for [this question of mine](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7603/79), I wanted to find nouns similar to *missile*.
I used the L&S on Perseus and [searched for all words ending in *-ile*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=ile&lang=la), but *missile* was not included.
The word is listed under the adjective *missilis*.

I wanted to find substantivized adjectives ending in *-ile*, but it appears that my preferred search tool will not show them at all.
Not all adjectives have established substantivizations, so searching for all adjectives ending in *-ilis* would have produced too much noise.

Is there an online Latin dictionary that allows to search for words by their ending and that lists *missile* separately from *missilis* (or at least shows *missile* in search results for words ending in *-ile*)?

Comment: Manually, you could consult a reverse dictionary, e.g. Part B: Voces ordinantur a tergo (pp. 279-546) in Gradentitz 1904 Laterculi vocum Latinarum https://archive.org/details/laterculivocuml00gradgoog/page/n291

Answer (score 2):

A brute force solution, based on the entry list of +12k [Latin nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Latin_nouns) available in Wiktionary:

1. Go to [this website](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/).
2. In the "Categories" tab, change "Project" to "wiktionary" and "Categories" to Latin nouns, as shown below.

[image]

3. In the "Output" tab, select CSV (to eliminate restriction on number of elements to return).
4. Click "Do it!" button. You should now get a CSV file, containing 12831 rows of Latin nouns.
5. Open the file in your favorite spreadsheet software and run a regular expression (regex) search of `\w*ile\b`. This should be done through something like "Find and Replace"" or so. After this, you should get a list of 28 nouns, as shown below (using LibreOffice).

[image]

Naturally, the usefulness of the method is restricted to the Wiktionary coverage of the Latin corpus (more precisely, to the indexation of existing Latin word pages to the Latin noun categories). The word *missile*, for instance, albeit part of Wiktionary, is not indexed as a noun, and therefore not included in the results above.

Comment: Wow! This tool is far heavier than what I expected to see... This is a good option to be aware of (+1), but I hope there are easier ways. And ways that see *missile*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta An even more brute force method would be to simply search the index of all Latin words and their declensions available. It seems however that there is no such list in Wiktionary.

Comment: If you list them all, it gives a whole lot of false positives. That might not be debilitating, but it would be nice to have access to attested substantivized adjectives with less noise.